# Dynamic Progress bar In WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have Many Page, and in each page I have to call the web service. for each call I need to show the Progressbar, and after the call returns I need to in visible the progress bar. this has to be done for Each Page.

Is there any way, to Show the Progress bar Dynamically when service call is invoked?

Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: That topic has already been discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521267/progressbar-on-every-page

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put the progress bar on the frame instead of on a page. 
Here's a blog entry that talks about how to add a MediaElement to the app's frame, but you can easily adapt it to display your progress bar control.
http://blog.jayway.com/2010/10/04/enable-background-audio-for-multiple-pages-in-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Actually this is about to Hear some sound in Background, but my requirement is different I need to see the progress bar loading when service is called. I need to add the Progerss bar to the Page at runtime. and make them visible...

Comment: You can use the same mechanism - put a grid in there and a progress bar, instead of the media element.

Comment: I made a short post about it (with progress bar). Hope it helps you get further. http://socialebola.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/omni-present-progress-bar-2/

Comment: @dinesh: Since it looks like you might want to use the ProgressBar in indeterminate state you should read this post by Jeff Wilcox and consider using his implementation instead of the standard control http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/

Comment: This does not seem to work with the Toolkit Transitions. Is there anything else I can do to implement this?