# ProgressBar on Every Page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need a progress bar to show up on most, if not all pages. Is there a good way to easily have the progress bar be on all pages?

I have a base page class that all my pages inherit from. I was thinking of just dynamically adding the progress bar to every page in the base class, but couldn't figure out how to do that. I would be able to just have the base page subscribe to a message (MVVM Light) and send a message when I want the progress bar to show or hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josh,

Check out this recent blog post by Jeff Wilcox.  He discusses is "old" way of using a single instance of a PerformanceProgressBar in his app (by modifying the RootFrame) and his new way (in Mango). I'm not sure if his new way would work in a pre-mango app, but you can check it out and see.

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/07/creating-a-global-progressindicator-experience-using-the-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-beta-2/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dynamically add the progressbar (hopefully you're using the PerformanceProgressBar which is now part of the toolkit) to the base page when needed, just add it to the base page, so it's always there, and then show/hide it as necessary.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant when I said dynamically adding it. Do you mean adding it in the xaml for the base page? I currently don't have one. If that's what you mean, I'm guessing I can easily do that. If you're talking about adding in C# code of the base page, then can you give me an example on how to do that? That's what I was talking about and didn't see a way to do it. I'm not terribly familiar with WPF/Silverlight yet.

Comment: And yes, I'm using the PerformanceProgressBar from the toolkit. :)

Comment: Can you give an example of this?