# Frame does not use Toolkit Transitions with ProgressBar inside Frame Template

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am switching to using a `ProgressBar`/`Grid` in the Frame of my application instead of via a `Popup`. I used this stack overflow post to get it working : [Dynamic Progress bar In WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839462/dynamic-progress-bar-in-wp7)

However, When using the example I no longer have page transitions. It will be hard for me to warrant the use of it if page transitions will not work properly. Is there something I'm missing? I tried setting the TargetType to "`TransitionFrame`", but that does not work properly and throws a `XAML` parse exception (for the namespace `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPages`)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LoadingIndicatorTemplate" TargetType="toolkit:TransitionFrame" >
                            <Grid x:Name="ClientArea">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                                <Grid x:Name="ProgressGrid" Background="Black" Opacity="0.85" Visibility="Collapsed" Loaded="ProgressGrid_Loaded">
                                    <StackPanel x:Name="Loading" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="tbLoading" Text="Loading" Style="{StaticResource TextNormalStyle}" />
                                        <ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource PerformanceProgressBar}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="pbLoading" Width="400" Margin="10" IsIndeterminate="False" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using the Toolkit's TransitionFrame for page transitions as well as a custom ControlTemplate to show your progress bar, you must specify the **TargetType** for the ControlTemplate as `toolkit:Transitionframe` where **toolkit** is defined as:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

The rest of the problem is that your ControlTemplate does not specify the template parts that the `TransitionFrame` requires. It requires two parts of type `ContentPresenter` named **FirstContentPresenter** and **SecondContentPresenter**. Change your ControlTemplate to the following to bring page transitions back:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LoadingIndicatorTemplate" TargetType="toolkit:TransitionFrame">
            <Grid x:Name="ClientArea">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="FirstContentPresenter" />
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="SecondContentPresenter" />
                <Grid x:Name="ProgressGrid"
                      Background="Black"
                      Opacity="0.85"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Loaded="ProgressGrid_Loaded">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Loading"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbLoading"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="Loading"
                                   Style="{StaticResource BoaTextNormalStyle}" />
                        <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar x:Name="pbLoading"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Width="400"
                                                        Margin="10"
                                                        IsIndeterminate="False" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

**NOTE:** Jeff Wilcox's `PerformanceProgressBar` is now part of the Silverlight Toolkit, so you can use it directly as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I tried this code before, but the issue remains the same. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: So with a correctly typed ControlTemplate and the right xmlns you _don't_ get a XamlParseException, you _do_ get your progress bar, but you _don't_ get the page transitions?

Comment: Yeah. The progress bar can show up fine, as do all the pages, but the actual page transitions no longer exist. I've updated the original post with the actual ControlTemplate.

Comment: The problem is missing template parts. I've updated my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was missing. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting the progressbar on the frame but then animating the page then the animation won't include the progressbar.

Why not just put the progressbar on the page?

Comment: The animation does not happen at all. I do not want the progress bar on the page because it can exist on the 30+ pages of the app.

Comment: @willmel: An app with 30+ pages seems like a navigation nightmare